# Reading images from all excel worksheets using Apache POI

Tags: excel, image, apache-poi

I am trying to copy all the images from all the worksheets from an existing excel file to a new excel file. For this, I read all the sheets from the existing excel file and copy the images to the new excel file. The following code accesses all the sheets and tries to copy all the images to the new sheet.

```
    public static void modifyExcelFile(XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, XmlException{
    String newFileName = "outputexcelfile.xlsx";
    XSSFWorkbook dest = new XSSFWorkbook("test.xlsx");

    int numSheets = xssfWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();

    // clone the template sheet additional number of times required
    for(int i=1; i<numSheets; i++){
        dest.cloneSheet(0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<numSheets; i++) {
        XSSFSheet destSheet = dest.getSheetAt(i);
        dest.setSheetName(i, xssfWorkbook.getSheetName(i));

        XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);
        // copy images
        System.out.println("Copying images ...");
        copyImages(sheet, destSheet);

    }

    writeFile(dest, newFileName);

}
```

test.xlsx is the template file with only one sheet. The following copyImages function tries to copy all the images from one sheet to the other.

```
    public static void copyImages(XSSFSheet from, XSSFSheet to) throws IOException, XmlException, InvalidFormatException{
    Drawing drawingPatriarch = to.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFWorkbook destWorkbook = to.getWorkbook();

    // Add image
    for (POIXMLDocumentPart pdp : from.getRelations()) {
        if (!XSSFRelation.DRAWINGS.getRelation().equals(pdp.getPackageRelationship().getRelationshipType())) continue;

        PackagePart drawPP = pdp.getPackagePart();
        WsDrDocument draw = WsDrDocument.Factory.parse(drawPP.getInputStream());


        for (CTTwoCellAnchor twoAnc : draw.getWsDr().getTwoCellAnchorList()) {
            String picId = twoAnc.getPic().getBlipFill().getBlip().getEmbed();
            PackageRelationship pr = drawPP.getRelationship(picId);
            PackagePart imgPP = drawPP.getRelatedPart(pr);

            System.out.println(imgPP.getPartName() + ": contentType: " + imgPP.getContentType() + " size: " + imgPP.getSize()
                    + ": picId: " + picId
                    +" - Col1: "+twoAnc.getFrom().getCol()
                    +" - Row1: "+twoAnc.getFrom().getRow()
                    +" - Col2: "+twoAnc.getTo().getCol()
                    +" - Row2: "+twoAnc.getTo().getRow()
            );

            // skip the logo
            if(twoAnc.getFrom().getCol()==0 && twoAnc.getFrom().getRow()==0)
                continue;

            try {
                InputStream is = imgPP.getInputStream();
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                int pictureIdx = destWorkbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                is.close();

                CreationHelper helper = destWorkbook.getCreationHelper();

                //add a picture shape
                ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
                //set top-left corner of the picture,

                anchor.setCol1(twoAnc.getFrom().getCol());
                anchor.setRow1(twoAnc.getFrom().getRow());
                anchor.setRow2(twoAnc.getTo().getRow());
                anchor.setCol2(twoAnc.getTo().getCol());
                Picture pict = drawingPatriarch.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

            }catch(IOException ioEx){
                System.out.println("Failed to add icons. Details: " + ioEx.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But if I run the code, it only copies images from the first sheet successfully. For all other sheets, images are not there. The code runs successfully without any errors. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding pict.resize(); function call after the Picture pict=... fixes the issue. So the modified code looks like the following:

```
   Picture pict = drawingPatriarch.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
   pict.resize();
```

Not sure why it doesn't work without the resize() call.

Comment: A [ClientAnchor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ClientAnchor.html) is not only top-left anchor cell to bottom-right anchor cell but top-left anchor cell + x/y offset in this cell to bottom-right anchor cell + x/y offset in this cell. The offsets are named `Dx1`, `Dy1` and `Dx2`, `Dy2` in `apache poi`.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Do I always need to mention Dx1-2, Dy1-2 if I don't call resize() function?

Comment: Yes, because if the picture fits into **one** cell, then top-left anchor cell and bottom-right anchor cell will be the same and so without the offsets, the picture size will be 0 dependent on the anchor. Then only resize() will correct to the native size.